# The sequence b [n] is a proportional sequence, and how do we find the general term formula for these known conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

The sequence b [n] is a proportional sequence with these known conditions

```
b[2] == 2, b[1] b[2] b[3] b[4] b[5] == 2^10
```

Why can't we find the general term formula using the following code?

```
RSolve[{b[2] == 2, b[1] b[2] b[3] b[4] b[5] == 2^10, 
  b[n]/b[n - 1] == b[n - 1]/b[n - 2]}, b[n], n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

**EDIT:** For the revised equations,

```
eqns = {b[2] == 2, b[1] b[2] b[3] b[4] b[5] == 2^10, 
   b[n]/b[n - 1] == b[n - 1]/b[n - 2]};

b[n_] = RSolveValue[eqns, b[n], n] // Simplify

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

RSolveValue::rsvb: There are multiple solution branches for the equations, but RSolveValue will return only one. Use RSolve to get all of the solution branches.

2^(-1 + n) *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqns

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: should be:```b[n]/b[n - 1] == b[n - 1]/b[n - 2]```

Comment: How can there be an error prompt in?

Comment: The result has been calculated, why is there an error prompt in the middle? What's the reason? Can it be eliminated?

Comment: Those are warning messages and it is up to the user to determine if the there is any actual problem. The solution verifies, so the returned solution is valid. However, the warning indicates that there could be others that are unidentified.